# Redpanda on minikube :volume claim size

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, redpanda

I've a question regarding the redpanda-operator on K8s. I'm currently using minikube and ran into an issue following this tutorial: https://docs.redpanda.com/docs/quickstart/kubernetes-qs-minikube/
Is it possible to change the volume claim size, since 100GB is a bit to much? Perhaps I have also overlooked something in the documentation.

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I really missed something. You can use a custom CRD. Here is the link to the documentation: https://doc.crds.dev/github.com/vectorizedio/redpanda/redpanda.vectorized.io/Cluster/v1alpha1@v22.1.2#spec-storage-capacity

Just add this to the one node clauster yml file:
storage:
capacity: 10Gi